# Is mutableCopy an Object's State or Behaviour?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, mutable

I personally adhere to the 'using dot notation in Objective-C with state, and messages with behaviour' principle. I don't want a conversation about this, but more whether the method, mutableCopy, is state, or behaviour?

Perhaps I should do more research on the difference between state and behaviour, but from what I know, I am not sure in this case.

Comment: `state and behaviour` some day you will stuck. Whenver you need to pass arguments you need to use [], even for behaviors without parameters `.` works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behavior. A copy of an object is not something related to "some specific property of the object". It's **creating a new object from an original one.** So please **do not** write

```
NSMutableArray *mutArr = array.mutableCopy;
```

Comment: Amazing response time and thank you very much for the advice.
I have indeed been foolishly writing .mutableCopy, but will not do from now on. I'll also actually change that in my existing code, because I'm the sort of guy who gets annoyed by inconsistency.

Comment: @InfinityJames You rock mate! I do that as well.

Comment: I hate this fact. I wish there were a shorter way to write `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:foo, bar, nil]`